# Positioning a BarLegend on ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I change the position of the legend of counter plot?
LegendPosition does not work in this case!
how can I do this for the following example?

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Because the option is named `PlotLegends` (note the plural form). Try `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"sine", "cosine"}, {0.8, -0.8}]]`; adjust the second argument of `Placed[]` as seen fit.

Comment: `LegendPosition` used to work in the days of Mathematica 6 or 7. It is obsolete now.

Comment: Thanks! it works.

Comment: what about for counter plots? it does not work for counter plot!

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
  Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {After, Center}]]`

Comment: "I want to do something" - [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/261109/edit) to include that information.

Comment: I want to change the position of legend of the contour plot. For example in this command ```ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]```, how can I change the place of the legend?

Answer (score 5):

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, All], {{i, j}}]
  ],
 {{i, 1.05}, 0.1, 2, 0.1},
 {{j, 0.1}, -1, 1, 0.1}
 ]
```

[image]